# ¿Por qué tenemos etiquetas Mongo y MongoDB?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

[mongo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo) y [mongodb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) significan la misma cosa, ¿no?

Comment: Sí. Incluso tienen la misma descripción en su wiki de etiqueta. Podríamos generar el sinónimo [TAG:MongoDB]← [TAG:mongo] (en [so] son sinónimos)

Answer (score 8):

Como dice @Mariano en el comentario, son lo mismo. Tenemos las dos etiquetas porque algunas personas prefieren escribirla de una manera o de otra.

Según [un artículo de *Wikipedia*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongo_(unidad_monetaria)), un *Mongo* es la moneda que está por debajo de un peso mongol (centavos o céntimos), pero en programación significa lo mismo que *MongoDB*, por el solo hecho de no incluir *DB* (DataBase o base de datos) en la palabra.

Ya he creado el sinónimo:

> [mongodb](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) (etiqueta maestra) ← [mongo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongo)

Comment: ese moderador :D  rapido y eficaz

Comment: gran trabajo hermano :D

Comment: @lois6b a veces un poco demasiado ;)

Answer (score 0):

Las personas que trabajan y conocen más sobre esta base NoSQL saben que su nombre propiamente dicho es MongoDB. Al hablar con personas que desconoce de que es y para que sirve es mejor utilizar el termino MongoDB (así encontraran la Documentación de manera rápida).

El termino Mongo se suele usar como una manera acortada o rápida, esto es común cuando hablamos con personas que están metidos en el mundo de MongoDB.

Comment: Ya se generó el sinónimo hace 6 días. Esto significa que todas las preguntas que estaban etiquetadas como [TAG:mongo] se convirtieron en [TAG:MongoDB], así como con cualquiera que intente etiquetar en el futuro, se mostrará la etiqueta [TAG:MongoDB]